# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor throwing TaskRejectedException in case of Spring 4.3.4 but not with 2.5.6

Tags: spring, spring-4, threadpoolexecutor

When we upgrade our application from Spring 2.5.6 to Spring 4.3.4.
We are getting 
TaskRejectedException due to ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in case of Spring 4.3.4 but not with 2.5.6

Is there anything changes in latest spring because of which it is failing.

Current configuration for ThreadPoolExcecutor:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
      <property name="corePoolSize" value="10" />
      <property name="maxPoolSize" value="80" />
      <property name="queueCapacity" value="80" />
  </bean>
```

It is throwing exception when maxPoolSize and queueCapacity value to 20 and 40 respectively.

This issue is there on only Windows platform and not on Unix machines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any exceptions caused by reference to files or database killing/locking threads? Why I asked is because as you mentioned this happens only on Windows.

Comment: Not able to edit question so pasting exception stack trace here.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5de8228c[Running, pool size = 20, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 20, completed tasks = 143]] did not accept task: org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster$1@6dc76851
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.java:296)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:130)

Comment: print the active threads to see if they are reducing. You may configure logger and set to show all logs from springsource.